# Is there a way to prevent an int value from deleting the first 0?

Tags: java, android

As the title says , for example I have the value 02 I want the first zero to stay there so I can control my pendingIntent.

my program basically has a list , every item has it's own options , the only way I can control alertmanager is by knowing the exact unique id so I can cancel the right notification , but I couldn't come up with a solution  other than this:

```
int FirstListPosition = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_FirstListPosition);
        int InnerListPosition = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_PASSEDPOSITION);
        String Merge = Integer.toString(FirstListPosition) + Integer.toString(InnerListPosition);
        int FinalValue = Integer.parseInt(Merge);
```

so if I click the first item in my main list , the FirstListPosition will be 0 and if I click the third item in my list inside of the main list the InnerListPosition  will be 2

so the string merge will be = 02 , this way the unique id will never be the same and I can actually get the position of the two if the user wanted to cancel a specific pendingintent " notification "

hopefully you guys understood what I meant

Comment: yes, do not use int use string ... next you can use some separator instead just joining (fx what if position > 9) fx "0|2|10" ... you can use int[] instead int ...

Comment: but the PendingIntent only except int as a unique value , I'm thinking of adding 1 to both , hopefully it'll work this way so the index will be from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). This class is intended to be used to format number according to a specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode the position in two lists into a single int value (and the number of choices in the second list is, say, less than 1000 you might use:

```
  int encodedListPositions;
  int list1Position;
  int list2Position;

  int encodedListPosition = list1Position*1000 + list2Position;

  ...
  list1Position = encodedListPosition / 1000;
  list2Position = endocedListPosition - 1000*list1Position;
```